# Wampserver and PHP Add ons

Tags: php, wampserver

I have WampServer2.2 with PHP 5.3.13 installed on my local machine. My hosting provider has PHP 5.4.4 installed on the web server.

I need to upgrade my local machine WampServer to use PHP 5.4.4. I have tried looking for an addon at http://www.wampserver.com/en/ but the latest i could find is 5.3.1. Can anyone advise where to find a PHP5.4.4 addon for wampserver2.2 or what i should do? I am quite new to wampserver and php so i apologise in advance if the answer is very obvious.

Comment: Upgrade and use version 2.4. That one seems to have PHP 5.4 on board.

Comment: you can install wamp for php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look on this site [wampserver site](http://www.wampserver.com/#download-wrapper) and it seams that you can download a wampserver with PHP5.4 inside.

I think it's the only one solution for you because if it not work you can compile your own PHP 5.4 from the official website http://php.net/downloads.php but it's really different to compile it on windows.